# UIAlertAction title color changed on pressed. How to solve?

Tags: objective-c, ios9, uialertaction

I want to change the title color of `UIAlertAction`. Now I am working on iOS 9. I am using the following code. When I press on the “Cancel” button its color changed.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"My Title" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"CANCEL" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    [self performSelector:@selector(cancelCliked:) withObject:nil];

}]];
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ASSIGN" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedstring = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"My Title"];
[attributedstring addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor vsBlueColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 8)];
[alertController setValue:attributedstring forKey:@"attributedMessage"];
alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {

    textField.placeholder = @"Enter text:";
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    textField.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

}];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

 -(void)cancelCliked:(id)sender{

UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: remove button titlecolor from cancel method..

Comment: you can also set. .[alertController.view setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];  remove & try

Comment: How to accesss alertcontroller on "cancelClicked"?

Comment: your problem is solved or not...you are  asking another question??

Comment: why are you creating another uibutton ?

Comment: when you press cancel button , arent you supposed to dismiis the alert controller ?

Comment: This question is really confusing. Are you trying to change a button's color when it is pressed and your problem is that you can't or is the problem the button's color does change and you don't want it to?

Comment: You do realize that `sender` in your `cancelCliked:` method will be `nil` because you pass `nil` in the call to `performSelector:withObject:`. And you do realize that the alert will be dismissed by the time your `cancelCliked` method is called. There's no point in trying to change any colors in the alert.

Comment: @rmaddy,yes you are right alert is dismissed when i click on 'cancel'.But at that fraction of time the 'cancel' button color automatically changed.I dont want that color change.

Comment: That's just the normal change you see when any button pressed.

Comment: @rmaddy,is it possible to change that behaviour?

Comment: There is no API that lets you change the look of the buttons of a `UIAlertController`.

Comment: can you come to chat?